# How to call parameters of parent intent in followup intent in dialog flow

Tags: artificial-intelligence, dialogflow-es, ibm-watson

I'm working with dialogflow and Facebook messenger to create a chatbot. I've one parent intent named as userdata and this intent has followed up intent named as custom intent. I've three parameters in userdata (Parent Intent) and I want to access parameters of parent intent in followed up intent. So if you've any idea about how to access parameters in followed up intent please share with me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lets say you have three parameters `param-a, param-b, param-c`.

You need to set a output-context in your parent intent (lets say `context-1`), then in your follow-up intent you can access the parameters of your parent intent as `#context-1.param-a`, `#context-1.param-b` and `#context-1.param-c`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Superb! Really helpful.